# psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction Using Unity of Work Pattern

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I using DDD to separete my modules using service, repository.

When i try to get all markets i get the FailedSqlTransaction

```
class MarketApplicationService:
    def __init__(self, market_repository: MarketRepository, market_domain_service: MarketDomainService, uow: AbstractUnitOfWork):
        self._market_repository = market_repository
        self._market_domain_service = market_domain_service
        self._uow = uow

     def get_markets(self, city_id: Optional[int] = None) -> List[Market]:
        logger.info("MARKET: Starting get markets")

        with self._uow:
            if city_id:
                market = self._market_repository.get_all_by_city_id(city_id)
                logger.info("MARKET: Finished get markets by filter")
                return market

            market = self._market_repository.get_all()
            logger.info("MARKET: Finished get markets")
            return market
```

Unity of Work Implementation:

```
class AbstractUnitOfWork(abc.ABC):
    def __enter__(self) -> AbstractUnitOfWork:
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.rollback()

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def commit(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def rollback(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class SqlAlchemyUnitOfWork(AbstractUnitOfWork):
    def __init__(self, session):
        self._session = session

    def __enter__(self):
        return super().__enter__()

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        super().__exit__(*args)
        self._session.close()

    def commit(self):
        try:
            self._session.commit()
        except IntegrityError as ex:
            if isinstance(ex.orig, UniqueViolation):
                raise DuplicatedRecord

    def rollback(self):
        self._session.rollback()
```

I cant reproduce this error local, but when i hosted my API in digital ocean often i get this error.

Comment: If you get this message it means that there has _already_ been an error on the connection that your session is using.  So you need to check your logs for errors that  precede this message.

Comment: You totally right, seems like my sessions has ben recycling and my close no closing properly